# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, illegalargumentexception

**Error**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appmaster.akash.messageplus, PID: 6468
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1525)
at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat$8.onDataChange(Chat.java:783)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzduz.zza(Unknown Source:13)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwu.zzbvb(Unknown Source:2)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxa.run(Unknown Source:65)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
12-19 15:11:35.658 1957-2011/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

**Code**

```
 if(mSeen!=null && mSeen.equals("No")) {
        if (mTime < seen)
             contentValues.put(KEY_SEEN, "Yes"); //Change the value of newData(which is actually your old value) by incrementing
                    long returnVariable = db.update(TABLE_CHAT_DATA, contentValues, null, null);
             if (returnVariable == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //-1 means there was an error updating the values
             } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "SEEEEEEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

}
```

The error is on the update line... I don't understand this because the data is right there and still showing empty values. Can someone help me out, please

Comment: what happens if you change `db.update` to `db.updateWithOnConflict` and set `CONFLICT_IGNORE` as its flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put brackets around the content of your first if-statement. The brackets are missing so the second line always executes, regardless of the if (I'm assuming that you don't enter values earlier for contentValues).

```
                  if (mTime < seen) { //// HERE
                        contentValues.put(KEY_SEEN, "Yes"); //Change the value of newData(which is actually your old value) by incrementing
                    long returnVariable = db.update(TABLE_CHAT_DATA, contentValues, null, null);
                   } /// AND HERE
                    if (returnVariable == -1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //-1 means there was an error updating the values
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "SEEEEEEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```